# What causes localhost 404 requests to go to http://origin.domain.com

Tags: apache-httpd

I've been running Apache on my local computer for years. Suddenly, any request to a local page that is not found, is redirected to http://origin.domain.com/. What could cause this?

Just to be clear, I open:

http://localhost/this_page_does_not_exists.html

And I am being forwarded to:

http://origin.domain.com

I tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and even in Lynx, and it happens all the same. Using Apache 2.2.22, on Arch Linux.

Comment: We would need to see your Apache configuration file. But I have a feeling this question should be on serverfault.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing the Apache configuration.

Comment: Additionally, it would be helpful if you would post the results of a [manual HTTP conversation](http://blog.alagad.com/2004/11/03/tutorial-on-sending-manual-http-requests/) with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check :

- your routing tables to localhost host
- your /etc/hosts file
- your access/error Apache log and see if the request gets in Apache, or forwarder by the OS beforehand

Comment: Turned out to be .htaccess file of the directory above the one in question.